# Convert EPOS to ESC/POS c#

Tags: c#, escpos, epos

i'm developing a software in C# that handles EPOS printing requests to any printer. As most of printers in market are able to print in ESC/POS, my goal is to convert EPOS to ESC/POS and print. Any idea how or acknowledge of some framework to convert EPOS to ESC/POS?

Best regards